# Music Buttons app --Multimedia volume and Phone calls

Tags: android

i have an app with buttons that on click are playing some mp3 sounds.i have two questions.Firstly,when i m trying to install my signed apk to my device,it says before the installation "allow this application to :read phone calls".How can i change it?i m not reading any phone calls in this app,its only a button play app.And secondly, if the app is running and i change the volume from the two buttons on the left,it changes the ringer volume...how could i fix it to change the mutimedia volume?thanks a lot

Comment: i realized that,when i click a button and the sound is playing,i can change the media volume.but when there is no sound playing i can change the ringer volume...

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure about your first question, but to set the volume buttons to control multimedia volume you would call `setVolumeControlStream(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC)` and then to change it back when you are done `setVolumeControlStream(AudioManager.STREAM_RING)`

Hope this helps!